# Prefetch data with RxJava

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2

I've a situation, where I need to prefetch data at the beginning of starting the application (Splash screen). I want to achieve this by using `RxJava`, but I'm kinda new to this library, so it's not going easy, haha.

I've `Loading Activity` and `Start Activity` in same sequence. While user is seeing `Loading Activity` I'd like to  fetch data so long, till observable returns answer (successful/error) and only then create `Start Activity`. How can I do this?

I read documentation and the best choice (imho) was `BehaviorSubject`. I usually handle network calls like this:

```
class DataRepository {
    private val retrofit = ..
    private val dataService = ..

    fun fetchData(): Single<DataModel> {
        return dataService.callToApi()
                 .map { apiObject ->
                     return@map jsonApiObject.data as DataModel
                 }
    }
}
```

In this case, `fetchData()` will return `Single`.
In `Loading Activity` I would call data repository:

```
private void getDataInLoadingActivity() {

    new DataRepository()
            .fetchData()
            .subscribe(response -> {
                ..do smth with response
            }, t -> {} );
}
```

Well,

**1.** I do not know how to implement `BehaviorSubject` with my example and situation.

**2.** In my instance, the call is async, that means, data might be fetched too late and `Start Activity` might be already created with-out the data I need. How can I avoid this? How can I make sure that `Start Activity` only starts when `LoadingActivity`, to be specific `getDataInLoadingActivity()` has returned any result?
Code sample would be great with comments.

Comment: If you develop asynchronous code, then you should accept that sometimes "the data is fetched later than something else happens". If you need strict guarantees, white synchronous code.

Comment: As for `Start` should happen only once `Load` is done - then start `LoadingActivity` should call to create `StartActivity` only from inside the subscription.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Your suggestion works, but I'm more interested in using `RxJava` for learning purposes. Got a solution for that? :)

Comment: See my second comment. You should "proceed" only when data response is received (if it's a `Mono/Single`) or otherwise when `Flowable` is completed.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Excuse me, I wasn't precise. `LoadingActivity` is actually `App.java` and `StartActivity` is `MainActivity`, so basically, they're not related.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean then. If you mean that until App does something there should be nothing on UI, as if the app has not started, then I'm afraid this would be a major source of frustration with your users. You should have something on your UI. Most apps use Splash screens for that, or loading masks and async events to the current activity that it should unmask.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Well, yes, I've Splash screen, but it would be more elegant if I could fetch/set data in `App.java`, not `Splash` because this application is also for AndroidTV, thus, with your suggestion, code would repeat in two places. `App.java` file is run by both platforms.

Comment: There is no problem with having this code in `App.java`, *if* you have a way of dispatching the "I'm done, close the splash and go on with your life" event to the splash so your app can move on to the actual meat of what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DataRepository` make a `Completable` that completes as soon as your data is fetched. Then just subscribe to that in your activity and start the next activity not before the `dataFetched()` completes.

```
class DataRepository {

    private var completedSubject = BehaviorSubject.create<Boolean>()

    fun dataFetched(): Completable {
        return completedSubject.take(1).toCompletable()
    }

    fun fetchData(): Single<DataModel> {
        return dataService.callToApi()
                .map { apiObject ->
                    return@map jsonApiObject.data as DataModel
                }.doOnSuccess { completedSubject.onNext(true) }
    }
}
```